# How to prevent index out of range crash?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

I am building a prototype player app which allows me to skip forward and backwards. The issue is when I skip to far or hit the previous button to many times the app crashes because "index out of range". I tried many things but could not solve this issue. This is my code. Thanks!

```
let player = AVPlayer()

var urlPlayerItems = [String]()

var currentTrack: Int = 0

    @IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (currentTrack - 1) < 0 {
        currentTrack = (urlPlayerItems.count - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (urlPlayerItems.count - 1)
    } else {
        currentTrack -= 1
    }

    playTrack()

}



@IBAction func didTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (currentTrack + 1) > urlPlayerItems.count {
        currentTrack = 0
    } else {
        currentTrack += 1
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Comment: In your `didTapNextButton` method you should probably change that `>` to `>=` because indexing on arrays usually starts at 0 and ends at `count - 1`.

Comment: Not only that, but you want `currentTrack >= urlPlayerItems.count - 1` (not + 1). If `currentTrack == urlPlayerItems.count` you're already out of bounds, and if `currentTrack == urlPlayerItems.count - 1`, you'll be out of bounds once you increment.

Comment: Similarly, you'd want `currentTrack == 0` for your `didTapPreviousButton` method

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would you mind adding the final code snippet? I'm super new at this.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that GUIs usually run on separate threads from the logic they control. As such, the user may be able to press buttons faster than actions are completed resulting in unexpected behavior. You may want to lock buttons until the associated action has completed

Answer (score 1):

```
let player = AVPlayer()

var urlPlayerItems = [String]()

var currentTrack: Int = 0

@IBAction func didTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentTrack >= 1 {
        currentTrack -= 1
    }

    playTrack()
}

@IBAction func didTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentTrack <= urlPlayerItems.count - 2 {
        currentTrack += 1
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I prevent the user from skipping to the first video again? Say the reach the end the only thing they can do is tap the previous button or vice versa? Also why did you change this line to the one you have if (currentTrack - 1) <= 0 { ?

Comment: If that's the case, you would want to change your code such that `currentTrack` only changes if it can increment or decrement (i.e you remove the first branch of your if-statements. I'll update my answer to show you

Comment: Ok please do! Thanks so much for the help! Would I need to also  disable the button somehow? if so how would I do that?

Comment: You could disable the button (I'm not sure how you'd do that). However, the functionality I have shown you should still work; the buttons simply won't do anything. Either approach would probably be acceptable

Comment: Ok great Ill try this out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply check if an index is valid in a given array, here's an extension that does just that:

```
extension Array {
    func canSupport(index: Int ) -> Bool {
        return index >= startIndex && index < endIndex
    }
}

let test = ["", ""]
print(test.canSupport(index: 0)) //prints true
print(test.canSupport(index: 2)) //prints false
```